# Injection from natural numbers to union of two aleph null sets.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Let $X$ and $Y$ be disjoint sets, each having cardinality of the set of all natural numbers. How do I see that there is an injection $f: \mathbb{N} \to X \cup Y$?

Comment: Do you mean bijection? Cause an injection is pretty silly. You can inject the naturals into any infinite set.

Comment: You have more hypotheses than you need. If $X$ has the cardinality of the set of all natural numbers, and if $Y$ is any set whatsoever, then there is an injection $f:\mathbb N\to X\cup Y.$ Are you sure the problem didn't ask for a ***bijection***?

Answer (score 2):

If $f\colon \mathbb{N}\to X$ and $g\colon \mathbb{N}\to Y$ are your bijections, then $f\colon \mathbb{N}\to X\cup Y$ is also an injection. Or you can use $g$.

Answer (score 2):

Since $X$ and $Y$ are countable there exists functions $f_X : \mathbb{N} \to X $ and $f_Y \mathbb{N} \to Y $ then you can define the piece wise function.

$$ f(z) = \begin{cases} f_X(\lfloor\frac{z}{2}\rfloor) & z \equiv0 \mod 2 \\ f_Y(\lfloor \frac{z}{2} \rfloor) & z\equiv1 \mod 2
\end{cases} $$

In other words all the even numbers get mapped to X and all the odd numbers get mapped to Y.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* Countable union of countable sets is countable.

Answer (score -2):

$$f: (\mathbb{N},\mathbb{N} )\to \mathbb{N}$$

$$(a,b)\to 2^{a}3^{b}$$

Obviously, it is injective

Comment: This answer doesn't make much sense.